# Loop through variable user names in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am looking to pull some configuration files from different users, all of which have their own user directory into a central config directory. The setup for these directories looks like

```
/home/master1
/home/master2
/home/master3
```

and so on. What I am wanting to do, is loop through these user directors using a format like masterN and pull a config file from all of them. It should be scalable.

It is a standard bash script, which I would like to add this functionality to.

I am unsure the best way to do this, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use shell globbing (pathname expansion):

```
for i in /home/master*; do echo "$i"; done
```

`*` expands to zero or more characters.

You can also use `?` which indicates any single character, or even character class `[0-9]`, which indicates any digit between `0` to `9` but these would not be scalable as these require fixed number of characters. If you are sure about the number of characters/digits (or the range for `[]`), then these are usable (or even brace expansion, `{..}`), otherwise `*` is the only option with *standard* globbing.